# How to shutdown default PHP server "php -S"

Tags: php, server, shutdown

I can start the default PHP server with
`php -S localhost:8000` but how to stop the server? Usually with CTRL + C yes, but if i want to do it from another terminal?

Comment: `ps aux | grep php` - find the process. `kill -9 1337` where `1337` is the process id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

starting:

```
nohup php -S localhost:8000 &
pid=$!
echo $pid >/var/run/php.pid
```

stopping

```
pid=$(cat /var/run/php.pid)
kill $pid
```

That's only an example without proper error handling

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal, run `htop`. Press `/` to search and type in `php -S` or `localhost` or whatever command you've entered, `F3` to search for next references if needed.
Press `F9` to kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

Find the process ID, and issue a kill command. On Ubuntu linux, you can use "top" command line utility to see and stop running processes.

Once you start top, use "L" to search for "php", and you'll se it's process id